# Are there also input controls similar to HTML5?

Tags: input, user-controls, aframe, interactive

Can I build 3D interactive websites with a-frame? I mean, are there input controls like in HTML5? Type text in a textbox, upload files control, buttons, show a floating window with some 2d rendered HTML, like a table, etc? And then of course, have these spatially set up.

I am building an app that can help studying for the 2D web. I can imagine that being fully immersed in the study environment, and interact spatially, can help you learn even faster with more focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, stuff must be built with WebGL. There are some early widget sets out there like aframe-material.